# Cocoa Application Crashing When Launched on Login

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I've found a bug in my application (SymSteam) which I'm having a particularly hard time fixing. It seems that whenever my application is launched as a login item it launches successfully but then crashes just a few seconds later. If the application is launched by the user (i.e. via Finder), it runs normally and doesn't crash.

Checking Console immediately after logging in, I see the following:

```
04/08/2012 18:51:47.437 SymSteam[187]: SteamApps exists & SteamAppsSymb exists, suggesting everything is A-OK.
04/08/2012 18:51:47.451 SymSteam[187]: Succesfully started observing everything I need to
04/08/2012 18:51:52.623 com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[124]: ([0x0-0x16016].com.simplecode.SymSteam[187]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11
```

The first two lines indicate that the my application started up fine and was able to register for the notifications it needed from NSWorkspace's notification centre. I can't figure out what's causing the segmentation fault though afterwards.

There's also a crash report too. Here's an excerpt of it:

```
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8 (12A269)
Report Version:  10

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: EXC_I386_GPFLT

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff80902278 _cache_getImp + 4
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff80903f51 lookUpMethod + 41
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff80905d5e class_respondsToSelector + 31
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff82adb7ab objectIsKindOfClass + 43
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff82adb812 __exceptionMatch + 18
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8090d1d4 _objc_exception_do_catch(objc_typeinfo*, objc_typeinfo*, void**, unsigned int) + 144
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff81621807 get_adjusted_ptr(std::type_info const*, std::type_info const*, void**) + 71
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff81621439 __gxx_personality_v0 + 889
8   libunwind.dylib                 0x00007fff8b678c22 _Unwind_RaiseException + 158
9   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff81621baa __cxa_rethrow + 72
10  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8090d5f5 objc_exception_rethrow + 40
11  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff82a7ce36 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 390
12  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8c855774 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 209
13  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8c855512 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 356
14  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8c8553a3 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62
15  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff87afefa3 _DPSNextEvent + 685
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff87afe862 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 128
17  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff87af5c03 -[NSApplication run] + 517
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff87a9a656 NSApplicationMain + 869
19  com.simplecode.SymSteam         0x0000000108df4d54 start + 52

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff82dad6d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff84c27f2c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff84c27cf3 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff84c121b1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff82dadd16 kevent + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff81bafe26 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 883
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff81bafa2a _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff82dad6d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff84c27f2c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff84c27cf3 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff84c121b1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff82dad6d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff84c27f2c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff84c27cf3 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff84c121b1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x1000000000000000  rbx: 0x00007fff70bf5810  rcx: 0x0000000000000001  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x1000000000000000  rsi: 0x00007fff88323f93  rbp: 0x00007fff56e0b910  rsp: 0x00007fff56e0b8d0
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x00000000510558d1  r11: 0x1000000000000000
  r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x1000000000000000  r15: 0x00007fff88323f93
  rip: 0x00007fff80902278  rfl: 0x0000000000010202  cr2: 0x00007fff88424000
Logical CPU: 0
```

I'm baffled as to what's causing the problem since the application doesn't crash when not launched at login and even when launched at login, it launches but then crashes a few seconds later. I don't know how to go about debugging this bug either as I can't set breakpoints or use Instruments on the program since the bug only happens on login.

Any advice on how to go about debugging this is greatly appreciated!

For what it's worth, my application is a background application (so it doesn't have a dock icon or main window), it uses the [Growl](http://growl.info) & [Sparkle](http://sparkle.andymatuschak.org) frameworks and it registers for notifications from NSWorkspace when it's launched.

**Update:**

Here's the code that's executed when my application is launched (some irrelevant code in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method has been omitted). As I said above, this all gets executed before the crash.

applicationDidFinishLaunching method:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
    [self.appController performInitialDriveScan];
    [self.appController startWatchingDrives];
}
```

`performInitialDriveScan:` simply uses NSFileManager a few times to see if certain directories exist. I won't post it here since it's quite long. I'm *pretty* confident it isn't the source of the crash.

`startWatchingDrives`:

```
- (void)startWatchingDrives{
    [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver:self.saController selector:@selector(didMountDrive:) name:NSWorkspaceDidMountNotification object:nil];
    [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver:self.saController selector:@selector(didUnMountDrive:) name:NSWorkspaceDidUnmountNotification object:nil];
    NSLog(@"Succesfully started observing everything I need to");
}
```

This just adds an observer to NSWorkspace's notification centre that watches for drives being mounted/unmounted.

That's everything that gets executed during the application's startup. The crash happens after the `startWatchingDrives` method is called and, as said above, only happens when the application is launched on login. It happens when my application isn't actually doing anything.

Comment: Well that's half the problem, I don't know what code to post since I can't find the source of the crash. I'll add the code that is executed when the application is launched but I'm not sure if it'll be much help.

Comment: Try using NSZombies,and post what you get.

Comment: @Programmer20005 NSZombies aren't much help since the crash only happens when the application is launched on login, when I don't have access to Xcode or Instruments. I enabled NSZombies in the application anyway and it didn't produce any more output in Console.app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done a little more debugging and managed to solve my own question. The overall cause of the crash is pretty uninteresting but here it is:

The application is starting up normally when the user logs in and it's registering for notifications of drive mounts/unmounts from NSWorkspace. Almost immediately after registering for notifications, it receives two notifications for the mounting of /home and /net during login. The `didMountDrive:` selector is performed by the notification and within the `didMountDrive:` method, I'm trying to get the 3rd path component of the drive that's just mounted's URL (since, if it was an external drive being mounted, this would be the name of the drive). That's where the program crashes since the /home and /net URLs only have two path components, so I'm trying to access an index out of the bounds of the URL's pathComponents array.

The fix was simply to check that there's at least 3 path components in the URL for the drive that was just mounted.